# Google+ doesn't work with jquery

Tags: jquery, google-plus-one, social-media

Im trying to implement google+ in a website that already has jquery in it, in firebug i get the message:

> "window.googleapisv0 is undefined".

I've implemented it like this

```
<div id="plusOne-root">
    <script src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone>
</div>
```

I also searched for the problem on google, more people experience this problem, but in their topics there's still no solution. I hope anyone can help me out.

Comment: Is the plusOne-root div in a tab or anything like that?

Comment: No it's just a div with that id, it has no extra meaning, omitting it would not lead to problems

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/) says "The script must be sourced from https"; could that be affecting your problem?

Comment: I just took your code and shoved it into a [jsFiddle with jQuery enabled](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/yRxeY/2/), and it seems to produce a +1 button just fine. Also, [my blog](http://gothick.org.uk/blog/) currently includes the +1 button on each entry, and uses both jQuery and jQuery UI. Can you provide a small, complete example that shows up your problem? It's going to be tough figuring out what's going on without being able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Show us your full code. Are you calling the google+ code before the document is ready or the div has loaded?

Comment: I see that is isn't a collision with jquery but with another script of mine, i can't show the full context cause im working on localhost

Answer (score 0):

This does not resolve the root cause but declaring this global would likely prevent the error from being thrown.

```
window.googleapisv0 = ( 'undefined' !== typeof window.googleapisv0 ) ? window.googleapisv0 : {};
```

Comment: FWIW, gratuitous globals are considered bad. But this appears to be a namespace with little collision likelihood.

Comment: I'd be pretty sure that masking errors in this way is a much worse thing to do than gratuitous globals... For a start you're just going to run into problems when you try to do anything with the object... Is there *any* merit to this answer?

Comment: If a third party has an error out of your control then yes, I think there's merit to preventing that third party from borking your page.

Comment: I guess it is possible that doing the above will make things actually work but I think more probably you will just still have no +1 button and now you will be running a bunch of dodgy code with hacks to make it not throw error messages... I'd have thought that a better answer would be to stop including the script...

Comment: This is not the answer to my problem since it is only covers it up, so google+ doesn't get shown